# flutter: Letting user to register using a specific qr

Tags: flutter

I'm new to flutter development. I would like to know how do I create a QR code specifically for a user with QR in order for them to sign up? Let's say QR1 signup for user1.
QR2 signup for user2. Both are totally different QR code. Can I do this using firebase dynamiclink?

Comment: QR codes are just Strings. You can make some strings for each user and use their userID in strings so the Strings are different. Then there are multiple packages that creates QR code from strings.

Comment: Thank you Arash! I would like to ask what if let say I let user create a username. and users have to buy a sticker of QR in order to create a number plate for the username and the QR code would be unique. How can I do that ?

Comment: I can think of two methods here. first the QR codes are premade, second the QR code will be made after user enters a unique username. for the first method, you need a database table to store key:value of the user:qrcode. like: (arash:sdfgtefgsdfg54fh).  And for the QR codes to be unique, you can create them based on the timestamps or just hash numbers with a salt. (there are a lot of ways to create unique strings). For the SECOND method, just create a string like this: username_qrcode. because the usernames are unique, Then the QR codes will be uniques too.

Comment: Alright Thanks buddy! you gave me some ideas ! :)